# Battery Doctor cleaning up the cache from my app

Tags: ios, image, caching, sandbox

I am working on social n/w app where I will be having lot of images consumed in the app. These  images are cached and I am using "Fast Image Cache" from "Path" for caching purpose.

I recently downloaded "Battery Doctor" app from app store https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/battery-doctor-master-battery/id446751279?mt=8

and cleaned up the cache from my device using this app.

After this I launched my app to check for images and all were gone.

Can some one tell me how other apps like the above one access the another apps sandbox as this is restricted by apple?

Thanks

Comment: They don't. They probably fill the disk which forces the OS to clean up cache folders.

Comment: @maddy: Does apple approve this kind of tricks?

Comment: They must since the App Store has plenty of these apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @rmaddy 
These kind of apps fill up the disk and RAM to force the OS cleanup. They probably do it multiple times and maybe/hopefully in some smart way.